# Questionable Output from Time Series Forecast Using MSTS and TBATS from R forecast package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Using historical daily order totals, I'm wanting to forecast the totals of the next 7 days. It's known in my field that these totals fall subject to weekly and yearly seasonal trends. Called `data`, below are the historical order totals for the past 795 days:

```
12  17  17 171 164 173 151  86  15 158 189 192 131 133  45  27 130 167 182 175 111  37  19 152 178 177 222 158  69  30 170 187 190 190 185  76  22 155 215 166 201 154  48  27 135 156 204 192 149  68  27 150 181 192 188 118  79  26 153 160 191 213 159  68  23 144 203 201 198 157  70  42 160 213 218 220 146  65  36 155 177 232 188 164  60  31 152 196 207 221 160  68 24 168 192 191 232 189  73  13 151 174 215 222 181  57  25 162 194 205 170 151  67  21 157 246 235 207 148  66  20 137 189 168 224 160  66  41 153 179 211 162 127  54  19 139 185 192 220 154  69  25 162 202 203 174 165  74  21  27 152 173 168 194  73  32 149 205 235 224 190 58  28 158 178 216 248 179  79  19 150 177 224 237 157  62  23 134 187 203 214 131 101  33 179 186  91 187 127  81  27 156 171 244 232 169  90  34 173 177 176 167 129  71  21 143 172 191 205 157  71  35 137 156 196 179 131 101  41 138 151 181 196 122  59  31 133 141 201 173 144  50  20 113 154 205 200 151  92  40 140 153 199 194 137  62  39  15 152 180 201 114  88 51 150 140 170 202 170  67  35 170 166 189 211 142  94  32 167 172 200 216 177  68  39 164 163 217 201 159  77  24 131 192 221 182 161  70  33 175 161 194 199 132  87  24 165 156 234 181 123  68  37 181 202 179 191 131  78  47 185 158 182 183 127  94  42 161 184 222 202 167 74  33 152 172 149  49  81  47  10 124 203 171 181 139  76  20 155 197 174 201 152  60  34 171 160 196 202 140  74  24 155 210 188 158 124  69  31  30   1 104   1 172 157  69  15   1 48  26 148 209 182 109  29 180 180 197 209 155  89  45 148 128 161 160 116  66  24 149 144 166 194 125  61  38 154 164 155 142 140  41  21 100 139 204 185 113  80  32 130 144 175 174 129  61  25 153 156 200 217 101  68  26 146 115 167 169 139  70  35 175 111 133 168 122  68 31 124 127 160 190 132  99  33 140 166 205 230 131  61  32 156 179 193 192 158  72  15 148 146 176 219 164  79  22 123 180 193 187 128  89  24 133 158 166 131 111  62  18 126 112 106 169 140  83  36 124 146 158 133 138  62  18 141 127 174 142 105  45  19 147 167 176 192 116 62  31 133 160 151 191 134  78  27  91 118 171 182 137  90  32 178 154 175 196 114  84  23 167 169 167 206 120  74  23 154 162 185 152 119  81  21 134 155 199 183 157  89  28 160 188 164  71  84  86  27 138 178 159 214 132  89  29 158 188 186 184 107  71  25 128 150 175 150 124  81  39 123 142 178 179 126  76  21 149 169 203 185 128  63  35 155 166 195 174 118  72 31 128 144 171 182 149  94  25 136 167 213 177 106  72  25  18 142 152 178 160 111  12 166 211 195 206 160  75  34 145 166 186 156 137  45  32 136 172 196 218 134  72  31 143 189 186 176 122  83  34 142 144 169 180 111  67  23 139 122 170 168 105  72  21 145 201 181 199  93 60  34 120 147 150 133  77  83  34 119 155 136 157 109  70  31 124 158 183 186  99  79  19 161 175 166 178 117  80  31 128 163 118  34  75  23  28 138 191 205 195 154  76  33 151 170 169 159  89  59  24  98 137 162 159 103  73  27 148  65 106  97  81  29 123  95   1   6  22 85  60  20 124 134 121 111  97  48  28 115 164 164 175 141  62  26 131 174 175 180 134  72 15 174 156 251 164 146  70   4  80 121 143 132  93  45  33 156 165 174 169 334  36  17 159 161 158 129 105  44  25 137 164 169 121  87  43  27
```

Using `ts.plot(data)` yields the following graph:
[image: OrderData]

Following along with http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/, my code to perform this forecasting follows:

```
myts<-msts(data, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
fit<-tbats(myts)
fc<-forecast(fit, h=7)
summary(fc)
plot(fc)
```

The range of values in `data` spans from 1 to 334. However, `summary(fc)' gives me forecast output of

```
> summary(fc)

Forecast method: TBATS(1, {5,5}, 1,{-})

Model Information:
BATS(1, {5,5}, 1, -)

Call: tbats(y = myts)

Parameters
  Lambda: 0.999952
  Alpha: 0.1874778
  Beta: 0.004592643
  Damping Parameter: 1
  AR coefficients: 0.4336 -1.171171 0.298187 -0.708633 -0.321975
  MA coefficients: -0.178688 1.155448 -0.175872 0.555014 0.152693

Seed States:
            [,1]
 [1,] 108.161300
 [2,]   3.930371
 [3,]   0.000000
 [4,]   0.000000
 [5,]   0.000000
 [6,]   0.000000
 [7,]   0.000000
 [8,]   0.000000
 [9,]   0.000000
[10,]   0.000000
[11,]   0.000000
[12,]   0.000000

Sigma: 9.027342e+72
AIC: 10999.28

Error measures:
                        ME         RMSE          MAE          MPE         MAPE        MASE
Training set -1.564113e+71 9.100417e+72 9.472706e+71 -5.89332e+71 1.561621e+72 1.80209e+70

Forecasts:
         Point Forecast        Lo 80         Hi 80        Lo 95         Hi 95
3.178082  -2.941534e+74 0.000000e+00 -2.824896e+74 0.000000e+00 -2.763152e+74
3.180822   3.428400e+73 2.150951e+73  4.705872e+73 1.474724e+73  5.382132e+73
3.183562   5.005464e+73 3.638168e+73  6.372778e+73 2.914374e+73  7.096597e+73
3.186301  -1.512812e+74 0.000000e+00 -1.362879e+74 0.000000e+00 -1.283509e+74
3.189041  -1.568978e+74 0.000000e+00 -1.379985e+74 0.000000e+00 -1.279939e+74
3.191781   8.620310e+72 0.000000e+00  2.809916e+73 0.000000e+00  3.841095e+73
3.194521  -2.646199e+74 0.000000e+00 -2.447683e+74 0.000000e+00 -2.342596e+74
```

With the addition of the forecast yielding a graph of:
[image: OrderData Plus Forecast]

So while my historical data ranges from 1-334, the point forecasts for the next 7 days using MSTS/TBATS are pushing magnitudes of 3e+74.

Needless to say, I'm quite confused as to how this output is so extreme. As far as I know I'm following the blueprint correctly to perform such forecasting. Does anyone know why I'm receiving such crazy numbers for my forecast?

I'll continue to triple-check everything but I'm at a complete loss as to what is going on. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly an example of this bug: https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/87

Comment: @RobHyndman: Thanks for your comment! This appears to be exactly what is going on. I'm glad to know I'm not crazy! The only thing that I could think of was that I was trying to include yearly seasonality with only just over 2 years of data. Is there anything that you would suggest I do as an alternative way to generate my forecast?

Comment: Try a Fourier regression with ARMA errors as explained at http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/

Comment: @RobHyndman: Will do. Thank you for your assistance and for your work on the forecast package

Comment: JRW- What an absolutely spectacular dataset. What is it?  What day does it start?  What country is this from?  Did you see how the day of the week pattern changed from day 1 and 2 to be low to 3 and 4 at period 360?  Or did you what looks like monthly seasonality?  If assuming your data starts at January 1st, look out for the four months that have seasonal bumps that occur every year.  In order of high to low June, September, Jult and October are higher than the other periods.

Comment: You didn't provide a beginning date so I can't be sure when your data starts and when those dates are higher, but they are there and occur systematically!   Of course, there are outliers too!

Comment: @JRW I have seen circumstances where AUTOBOX has detected a change from day-1;day-2 TO day-3;day-4 . It occurred when somebody inadvertently omitted two days of data. Such superior detection schemes are often very important in cleaning up both bad data and/or bad analysis. Tools that actually challenge the internal consistency of the data patterns are a sheer joy to use and highlight what is wrong with simply assuming model form.